# Reading ".rec" file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have timeseries sensor data (temperature, vibration) in `.rec` files. I am looking a way to import them using Python. What I read while finding a solution for this is, usually `.rec` file contains images (medical images). In my case it is time series data. There is tools such as [MXnet](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.9.0/) and [MNE](https://mne.tools/stable/index.html). But they use `.idx` files along with `.rec` files to iterate. Also, examples are limited to images.

Currently, what I am doing is to change the extension to `.csv` ans importing using pandas (delimiter '\t'). It is working as intended but I am looking for a clean solution that directly allows me to read and in best case scenario to iterate on `.rec` files.

Comment: Just do the same as you are doing now except renaming the file to `.csv`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, It worked. that was very trivial... I should have tried that on the first place. Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.